# \xskakget with \newchessgame is failing

Tags: xskak

I'm trying to get the last move id of a chess game using `\xskakget` and `\newchessgame` like this.

```
\newchessgame[id=someid, moveid=10b]
```

and after sometime, use `\mainline` to display the move.

```
\newchessgame[id=someid, moveid=\Xskaksomeidnextmoveid]\mainline{10...Nf6}
```

When compiled with xelatex, I'm getting 'Undefined control sequence error \@nnil ->\@nil. `\Xskaksomeidnextmoveid` itself is showing the correct value, but when inside \newchessgame, I'm getting this error. Please bear with me if this is a silly question. I'm a latex newbie.

EDIT:

Simple working example is here. The commented out line before `\end{document}` is the culprit.

```
\documentclass[9pt]{book}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage{xskak}
\usepackage{chessboard}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[H]
  \begin{floatrow}[2]
    \newchessgame[id=da, moveid=1w]
    \ffigbox{\caption{}}{\chessboard[
        setfen=rnbqkbnr/pppppppp/8/8/8/8/PPPPPPPP/RNBQKBNR
    ]}
  \end{floatrow}
\end{figure}

\newchessgame[id=da, moveid=1w]\mainline{1. e4 e5}

\Xskakdanextmoveid

%% \newchessgame[id=da, moveid=\Xskakdanextmoveid]\mainline{2. Nf6}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Show a complete example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

New games reset quite a lot informations. I could perhaps define it so that `\Xskakdanextmoveid` gives some default like "1w". But it will never give "2w" as you seem to expect.

Either use a new id (and set the position too!):

```
\newchessgame[id=dum,moveid=\Xskakdanextmoveid,setfen=\Xskakdalastfen,print]
```

or use `\resumechessgame` which is intended for this sort of things:

```
\resumechessgame[id=da,moveid=\Xskakdanextmoveid]
```

or  simpler:

```
\resumechessgame[id=da]
```